# how to check the size of sharepoint 2007 site collection without having access to central admin

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

how to check the size of sharepoint 2007 site collection without having access to central admin

Note :- storage quota not defined so not able to see from site settings storage space allocation.

please let me know is there any other way to check the site collection size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three methods

1. via SharePoint Designer

   - Open Sharepoint Designer .
   - Right Click on the site name on the Folder List > properties ,
2. Or via Site Setting

[image]

[image].

For more details check [this](https://irrationalsanity.wordpress.com/2009/02/22/finding-buried-treasure-built-in-usage-reports-in-sharepoint-and-search-server/)

2. Via code

Try to cre3ate a console application with this code

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite(“http://blr3r7-19c:13774/sites/testwp”);
 DataTable oDtRawData = null;

 // this line of code will return the stroage information of all the document lirbaries in this site
 oDtRawData = oSite.StorageManagementInformation(SPSite.StorageManagementInformationType.DocumentLibrary,SPSite.StorageManagementSortOrder.Increasing, SPSite.StorageManagementSortedOn.Size,100);

 // this line of code will return the stroage information of all the lists in this site
 oDtRawData = oSite.StorageManagementInformation(SPSite.StorageManagementInformationType.List, SPSite.StorageManagementSortOrder.Increasing, SPSite.StorageManagementSortedOn.Size, 100);

 // this line of code will return the stroage information of all the Documents in this site
 oDtRawData = oSite.StorageManagementInformation(SPSite.StorageManagementInformationType.Document, SPSite.StorageManagementSortOrder.Increasing, SPSite.StorageManagementSortedOn.Size, 100);

 // if you wan to see column names, loop through all the columns and find out the names and grab the needed one. 
 foreach (DataColumn oColumn in oDtRawData.Columns)
   {
            Console.WriteLine(oColumn.ColumnName);                
   }
 Console.ReadLine();

 // loop through all the rows and find out the values. Here the size will be return in bytes (size/1024 = size in KBs)
  foreach (DataRow oRow in oDtRawData.Rows)
   {
         Console.WriteLine(oRow[“Title”].ToString() + ” : “ + oRow[“Size”].ToString() + ” : “ + oRow[“LeafName”].ToString());               
  }

Console.ReadLine();
```

Code Ref : [How to find out the storage space allocation details a site through code.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2008/11/14/how-to-find-out-the-storage-space-allocation-details-a-site-through-code/)

Comment: Designer worked for me, though i could not get the screen as you have shown in SharePoint Site Collection / Site Settings.

Answer (score 2):

As an Site Owner (and not a Site Collection Admin) you should be able to connect to your site using SharePoint Designer. Once connected, you can click on Site->Reports->Site Summary. This report shows All Files and the total size in KB of all files on your site.

Comment: This is perfectly working for me.